# What's the definition of "transit" for the South Korea 30 day visa exemption program?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, south-korea, terminology

I am planning to travel to Seoul and Bangkok for a holiday trip. I hold a Chinese passport and I am studying in Australia (so I also have a valid Australia student visa). My plan is to go Australia -> Seoul (enter via Incheon Airport, stay for a week) -> Bangkok (stay for another week) -> Australia.

It seems to me that this route should satisfy the 'B-2-1 transit visa', which is the 30 day visa exemption scheme (i.e., I directly fly from Australia to Korea, I have an onward ticket to depart Korea to a third country within 30 days, and I have an Australian visa). I am posting here just to double check (really don't want to mess up) and would like to see if other people might have similar experiences/questions.

I tried to email the South Korea Consulate but never got a reply from them :-(

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

According to Timatic (the system airlines use to confirm visa requirements), the relevant rules for you to be exempt from requiring a visa for South Korea are :

> Nationals of China (People's Rep.) with an entry visa issued by
> **Australia**, Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus,
> Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary,
> Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania,
> Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal,
> Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United
> Kingdom for **a maximum stay of 30 days**. They must:
>
> - arrive from a third country and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 30 days to the country that issued the visa; or
> - **arrive from the country that issued the visa and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 30 days.**
>
> **The entry visa must be in the form of visa sticker on the passport, except
> for Australian visas.** If passengers have a transit point before
> arriving in Korea (Rep.) or after leaving Korea (Rep.), the maximum
> stay in that transit country must be within 3 days.

The final sentence there is a little confusing, but appears to refer to a transit stay between the country that issued the visa and South Korea - which on your trip to Korea you do not have.  This would leave you eligible under the 2nd condition above (in bold).

If you were coming from a country other then Australia then you would not be eligible - the bolded condition would not apply, and the earlier condition (onward flight to Australia) would also not apply due to your more than 3 day 'transit' stay in Bangkok.  However as you are coming directly FROM Australia this should not be relevant - from the perspective of Korean immigration, you are travelling from Australia to Bangkok with a stop in Korea.

The statement that a physical visa sticker is not required is due to the fact that Australia no longer issues visa stickers. I would strongly recommend printing out the details of your visa from the VEVO system and taking that with you as proof of your visa status.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help! I will make sure that I print out all the necessary documents :-)